# Changing a member's nickname with JDA

Tags: discord-jda

I am trying to change someones nickname, but I keep getting this error: `net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.HierarchyException: Can't modify a member with higher or equal highest role than yourself!`

This is my code:

```
Member m = e.getMember();
m.modifyNickname(rank.getDisplayName() + " | " + p.getName()).queue();
```

Comment: Nevermind! It was because I owned the server.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, whenever a bot tries to modify the:

- Nickname
- Role

Or tries to:

- Kick
- Ban
- Timeout

a user, Discord will check if the user is allowed to do so.
This is checked by Discord looking if the bot has a role higher, **then the highest role the user it tries to effect has.**.

In JDA, there should be a util for this. PermissionUtil.canInteract(Member, Member). However, as far as I could find. This is something JDA internal, and should not be used.

In your case, you are either above the bot, or you're the owner. (Whom is always the highest and always has admin)